# Cpanel/WHM: running PHP with PHP-FPM in Apache2

Tags: apache-http-server, php, cpanel

I have this CentOS 6.9 VPS server with cpanel and WHM, running Apache 2 with PHP 5.6

Ive enabled PHP-FPM on WHM and it shows as active in both WHM and Cpanel (in the MultiPHP manager sections)

To be sure, I even copied it to the conf where Im setting my vhost.

And PHP-FPM seems to be running, according to its logs ("NOTICE: ready to handle connections" on the php-fpm error.log)

But when I go see phpinfo(), it still says:

```
Server API CGI/FastCGI
```

So what am I missing? How to debug this? Ive restarted apache and php-fpm many times, and even rebooted the server, to no avail

**EDIT**: actually, I was wrong: I didint have that on my vhost config:

```
<IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
<FilesMatch \.(phtml|php[0-9]*)$>
SetHandler proxy:unix:/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/var/run/php-fpm/fc680a9025c37fd635d3cad33dda11786afdf8c0.sock|fcgi://domain.tld
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

It must have been overwrote by something. Now if I place it there I get an error:

```
No input file specified.
```

Even when I try to access the script with just phpinfo() on it

Answer (score 0):

cPanelMichael gives an answer at this cPanel forum page that might help to clarify: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/php-handlers-in-easyapache4.592879/

Essentially, the way PHP-FPM is implemented in cPanel at the moment, it can only be enabled per domain, but isn't actually available as a global or system-wide PHP handler.  So globally, you can have DSO, suPHP, or fcgi as your global handler, but then be able to enable PHP-FPM for a specific domain.  However, if phpinfo(), when called from the domain for which you've enabled PHP-FPM, isn't showing any evidence of PHP-FPM working for that domain, then there may be an issue that a systems administrator at your data host with root access to your server would be in a much better position to investigate.

Does your phpinfo() at least show --enable-fpm or --with-fpm-systemd in the Configure Command section?  Does php-fpm show as 'active' under the cgi-fcgi section further down the phpinfo() page?  Is there a fpm.config directive?  I'd say if you find at least the configure command options, you might be fine.  If Ctrl+F -> 'fpm' doesn't return any results, however, again I'd contact the technical support at the data hosting company you're hosting your cPanel account with.

Comment: no to everything, no mention of fpm anywhere on the info. Ill keep trying a bit more (I do have root access for the VPS)

Comment: also, my description of the problem was wrong, Ive updated the question. Please see if that provides any useful information

Comment: If your vhost config is in the main httpd.conf, your changes are liable to get overwritten by cPanel updates without proper distillation of the Apache configuration (which is a term used to describe the process of informing cPanel of your changes so that cPanel preserves them across rebuilds).  However, in a functional cPanel environment, it shouldn't be necessary to manually set PHP-FPM in that way.  If Enabling it in the multiphp section of WHM, or from within a domain's cPanel, is failing, then a vhost entry is a workaround at best.  Are you accessing phpinfo() from the domain your testing?

Comment: yep, from the same domain. Ive tried to manually set PHP-FPM because just activating it from the pannel wanst working. Also,l Ive separated my vhosts from the http.conf now

Comment: Even separating out your vhosts from the main config file, you probably have to place an include statement in your main config file, which itself could get overridden.  I also manage a cPanel server, and I avoid directly modifying the Apache configuration and simply make changes to it through the WHM interface, so that my changes are preserved in cPanel's config templates.  Must you make a direct mod to the Apache conf without going through cPanel, run '/usr/local/cpanel/bin/apache_conf_distiller --update' afterward, but even that no longer guarantees cPanel won't overwrite your changes ever.

Comment: Try running updates. upcp to update cPanel itself, and yum update as root to make sure CentOS is updated. If you have to wait until non-business hours, that's understandable, but it might not hurt to try rebuilding your Apache and PHP configuration with EA4 and then retesting your domains after toggling the PHP-FPM switches and checking phpinfo() by accessing it on the domain in testing (so if you're testing phpfpm.com, place <?php echo phpinfo(); ?> inside phpfpm.com/phpinfo.php and access that). Check for the presence of FPM. If it's still not working, you need other admins with root access.